# Oracle SQL split one record into many records

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Let's say I have a table with a record like so:

```
ID  Yr      MonthNumber     Type                Amount
2   2020                    Annual Forecast     12,000
```

Then let's say I want to remove this record from the table and insert the same value spread evenly at a monthly frequency like so:

```
ID  Yr      MonthNumber     Type                Amount
4   2020    1               Monthly Forecast    1,000
5   2020    2               Monthly Forecast    1,000
6   2020    3               Monthly Forecast    1,000
7   2020    4               Monthly Forecast    1,000
8   2020    5               Monthly Forecast    1,000
9   2020    6               Monthly Forecast    1,000
10  2020    7               Monthly Forecast    1,000
11  2020    8               Monthly Forecast    1,000
12  2020    9               Monthly Forecast    1,000
13  2020    10              Monthly Forecast    1,000
14  2020    11              Monthly Forecast    1,000
15  2020    12              Monthly Forecast    1,000
```

Is there any easy way to accomplish this?  I have a table that has both monthly and annual data, so I want to make the frequency all the same.  Maybe a procedure that starts 'For Each Row where Type = 'Annual Forecast'.... but I don't know the right syntax.

UPDATE: FINAL SOLUTION
I put in the real fields that are being used in this case.  Answer inspired by HepC solution below.  Thank you!

```
INSERT INTO STG_DFF_B("Forecast Month","Publish Date","FinancialPlanType","Subaccount","ITN","Project ID","Resource Type","Details",UNIT,VALS,MONTHNUMBER,"YR")
SELECT "Forecast Month",
    "Publish Date",
    "FinancialPlanType",
    "Subaccount",
    ITN,
    "Project ID",
    "Resource Type",
    "Details",
    UNIT,
    ROUND(VALS/12,2),
    x.lvl,
    "YR"
FROM STG_DFF_B
CROSS JOIN (SELECT LEVEL AS lvl -- Joins in 1 through 12.
           FROM dual
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12) x
WHERE MONTHNUMBER is null;
```

Comment: Are there any cases where your data contains a Monthly Forecast where there is also a Annual Forecast for the same year? If not, you can use simple SQL statements instead of PL/SQL. And even if there are, the SQL just leverages `MERGE` instead of `INSERT`. A little less well known, but still very small.

Comment: good question..no the annual forecast will always be different years from the monthly. I didn't know about MERGE.. looked at the documentation quickly and that looks like it would be it!  Thank you!

Comment: "Grain" is used in some contexts as a technical term, with a different meaning than you intend. Best call it "frequency" to avoid confusion.

Comment: There's something I don't understand. What is happening with the ID? Isn't that something that should be UNCHANGED? For example, if it is a loan ID, or a tenant ID, etc., it shouldn't change. If it does change, where do the numbers come from (why 4 through 15, and not 2 through 13 or any other sequence)?

Comment: Nothing happening with ID...just wanted to point that it should remove the annual record and insert 12 new records with the annual figure replace and spread evenly.  It's just the table primary/unique key.

Comment: Grain is a technical term used in data warehousing if I'm not mistaken and I believe the way that I'm referring to it is correct, but if I'm mistaken please give further explanation.

Comment: The grain is the set of attributes (columns) that uniquely identify the smallest bit of data. For example, in a SALES table, it may be "revenue by product, store and month". The table may include other columns (like SUPPLIER or REGION etc.) but the grain is (product, store, month). You may choose to go from MONTH to DAY (have higher frequency), but this doesn't "change the grain from month to day". The concepts may be somewhat related (as in this example), but "grain" doesn't mean "frequency". For example keeping "month" as is but changing from "store" to "country" also changes the "grain".

Comment: interesting nuance...thank you for the explanation.. will keep in mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the requirements and data quality you've described I would probably do something along the lines of the following.

```
INSERT INTO sample_table
SELECT sample_seq.nextval
      ,st.yr
      ,x.lvl
      ,'Monthly Forecast'
      ,st.amount / 12 -- Maybe with ROUND or TRUNC? Depends.
  FROM sample_table st
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT LEVEL AS lvl -- Joins in 1 through 12.
               FROM dual
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12) x
 WHERE st.type = 'Annual Forecast'
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL -- Not already present as month (reentrant scripting)
                     FROM sample_table stm
                    WHERE stm.yr = st.yr
                      AND stm.monthnumber IS NOT NULL);

DELETE FROM sample_table st WHERE st.type = 'Annual Forecast';
```

Comment: Thanks Hep...will give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Just a bit modified tweak . Hope this helps too.

```
INSERT INTO DUMM
SELECT level+a.id id,
  a.yr,
  level,
  'Monthly Forecast' TYP,
  ROUND(a.amt/12) amt
FROM DUMM a
  CONNECT BY level <= DECODE(a.TYP,'Annual Forecast',12,'Monthly Forecast',6,'Quarterly Forecast',4);

DELETE DUMM WHERE TYP = 'Annual Forecast';
```